# How to beat Phantom Train?

Tags: final-fantasy-6

Been playing Final Fantasy VI again because of having more free time on my hands and I haven't played it in years.

**HOW THE HELL DID I BEAT THE PHANTOM TRAIN BEFORE?!**

My version on this play through as my characters all have strange names like `Mash` instead of `Sabin`, but I can't see that as a reason as to why he totally trashes me. I still have Shadow in my party and I don't feel particularly under-levelled. I'm around 75% sure I can finish him with a `Pheonix Down` but this always feels dirty to me.

Is there something I should know about? Or am I just going to have to level up?

Comment: I'm... Fairly sure a Phoenix down kills it in one hit. And there is no shame in that. =P

Comment: @Fluttershy It's not just that, but I feel like there is a reason I'm not beating him and I want to address it

Comment: By suplexing the damn thing, clearly. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Phantom Train's weakness is Fire, Lightning, and Pearl (any cure-type attack).

If you reeeeeallly don't want to use a Phoenix Down (which kills him in one shot),  just have Sabin use Aurabolt, Shadow throw Shurikens, and Cyan perform his third Swordtech skill, which may be Slash or Dispatch.  He'll go down eventually.

You can also use potions to chip away at his HP if any of your party gets imped.

Comment: Shadow has no Shurikens. I have no idea what `Dispatch` is, like I said my version is different.

Comment: Use his first or his third swordtech skill.  I think `Slash` is his first and `Dispatch` his third.

Comment: Ah found it. That worked a treat. It's called `Fang` in my version. How strange

Comment: The re-translated script (e.g. the GBA version) uses notably different names for the SwordTech skills.

Answer (score -4):

The Lazy Way -
Pheonix Down

The Legit Way - 
Retort, Autocrossbow, and Cure / Bolt the life (Or death?) out of it.

The Thug Way -
SUUUUPPLLEEEEXXXX!!!!

The Conservative Way - 
Fight
Fight
Fight
Fight

I think I covered it all